# HTML trouble: multiple Divs float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm sitting now 1 hour working on this problem: How to make "Field Item 2" float at the right site of "Field Item 1" Is that possible with CSS at all? Or are there too may divs in between?
Any idea? Tanx a lot!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test float</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="group-header user-slogan">
        <div class="field field-name-field-user-slogan field-type-text field-label-hidden">
            <div class="field-items">
                <div class="field-item even">Field Item1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="even zitatgeber" style="float:left;">Field Item2</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: we definitely need css, make a jsfiddle. Maybe float right would help you :)

Comment: I guess there are more divs than needed. You cannot float it right unless it is inside its parant which has a class field-item even div. And why did you inline styled as float:left?

Comment: @Yagiz I thought that float left would do it...just a try...thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this, add style="float:left;" into the div which is in the same level with the Field Item2, and change the style of Field Item2 to float:right. Here it is:

```
<body>
<div class="group-header user-slogan">
    <div class="field field-name-field-user-slogan field-type-text field-label-hidden" style="float:left;">
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even">Field Item1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="even zitatgeber" style="float:right;">Field Item2</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Remember to add the specific width for the left and right, so the item will float correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use float:left on both the divs

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you should specify width for your parent div and take the div you want to float inside it(parent).

Try this :

```
<html>
<title>Test float</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="group-header user-slogan">
    <div class="field field-name-field-user-slogan field-type-text field-label-hidden">
        <div class="field-items" style="width: AAApx;">
            <div class="field-item even" style="float:left;">Field Item1</div>
            <div class="even zitatgeber" style="float:left;">Field Item2</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can also float the second item div to the right if the parent div behaves as a block level element